# How to get all the id elements values in a array from html form using jquery

Tags: jquery

Sample HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    <ul id="tabs_nav">
      <li id="t_00">data1</li>
      <li id="t_01">data2</li>
      <li id="t_02">data3</li>
      <li id="t_03">data4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <ul id="tabs_nav">
      <li id="t_04">data5</li>
      <li id="t_05">data6</li>
      <li id="t_06">data7</li>
      <li id="t_07">data8</li>
    </ul>
  </div>        
</body>
```

Here I would like to get the all the id values in a array. As expected I should get the total id count should be 12 and able to read all the values in array.

Please help me, how to perform the above action using `Jquery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the above using following code

```
var arr = [];
$( "*" ).each(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     if(id !== undefined) {
         arr.push(id);
     }
});
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/3oHvyhuH5UQPv0IAYEXD?p=preview

Comment: @DelwinSamuel Just as a side note, you cannot find worst selector than `'*'`. I'm not begging here but accepting this answer is quite funny in some way... :)

Comment: @A.Wolff - I agree with you on this, however, it would have been more appropriate to comment in question rather than answer :) DelwinSamuel - Please unaccept the answer as it is not a performance oriented solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can map it:

```
$(function(){
    var arrIds = $('body [id]').map(function(){
        return this.id;
    })/*.get()*/; // get() to get a true array
    console.log(arrIds); // outputs: ["div1", "tabs_nav", "t_00", "t_01", "t_02", "t_03", "div2", "tabs_nav", "t_04", "t_05", "t_06", "t_07"]
    console.log(arrIds.length); // outputs: 12
});
```